# H&M and Nike are facing a boycott

Tags: pronunciation

Is Nike pronounced as /ˈnaɪkiː/ (in UK)? Or /ˈnaɪk/?

I've checked it out in dictionaries and found it is pronounced as /ˈnaɪkiː/ when it means a goddess or a missile; yet in the context below, it is the name of a shoe company (world-renowned). The sound of its Chinese translation is like /ˈnaɪk/.  Hence the thread.

> Xinjiang cotton: **H&M and Nike are facing a boycott** in China over Uyghur forced labor statements

> Source: [CNN](https://www.msn.com/en-us/news/world/handm-and-nike-are-facing-a-boycott-in-china-over-xinjiang-cotton-statements/ar-BB1eWYv1?ocid=uxbndlbing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Wikipedia, the company is named after the Greek goddess, so it should be pronounced like the goddess, /ˈnaɪki/, and a note in the article says that is the "official" pronunciation. But the note also says that /ˈnaɪk/ is common outside of the US.